# Retrieve HTML from links on page

Tags: c#, html, streamwriter

I am using the following method to retrieve the source code from my website-

```
class WorkerClass1
{
    public static string getSourceCode(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        return sourceCode;
    }
}
```

And then implement the `WorkerClass1` as so-

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = textBox1.Text;
        string sourceCode = WorkerClass1.getSourceCode(url);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"path");
        sw.Write(sourceCode);
        sw.Close();

    }
```

This works great and retrieves the HTML from my home page, however there are links at the bottom the page which I want to follow once the first page has been retrieved.

Is there a way I could modify my current code to do this?

Comment: You should check out the excellent HTMLAgility pack from here: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ - this takes a lot of the pain out of parsing HTML. You can then extract links from your main page and then do an HttpWebRequest for each link and so on - sounds like you are basically building a spider / bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course.

What I would do is to read the HTML using a regular expression looking for links. For each match, I would put those links in a queue or similar data structure, and then use the same method for looking at that source.

Consider looking at HTMLAgilityPack for the parsing, it might be easier, even though looking for links should be quite simpele using Google.

Comment: Implemented the htmlAgilityPack and got it to navigate through the pages thanks.